# How to make cool hi-hats sounds in Reason

Tags: reason

I listened to this very neat track from Chet Faker, and I was stunned by the hi-hats sound beginning at 0:18.
I was wondering how to recreate it in Reason, and I figured maybe it would serve as an example to make guidelines on how to process hi-hats sounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a lot of stereo panning back and forth on the hihats supplemented by the clicks left and right. There is also some tight echo on the hats - notice also how the rest of the musicical instruments (apart from the scratches) do not impose on the mid upper and upper bounds of the spectrum thus leaving the hats and clicks to stand out proud and not clashing with other stuff.

I can't tell you how to recreate it in reason but if you were using cubase I'd have them perked up with some eq from about 2kHz to 10kHz (maybe 6 dB plateau), then i'd compress them with a ratio of about 5:1 so that the levels are nearly always causing compression to be instigated i.e. the threshold of compression is mainly below all the hihat sounds. Then I'd have an automation track doing the fast panning left and right. Then further down the chain I'd use some echo - not blatent - 50ms delay to 200ms should do it. Finally it sounds like they have been distorted a tad so whatever distortion fx you have might be worth a mess with.

Comment: There seem to be an aspiration effect or something like that, I was thinking maybe a gated reverb, but I wouldn't know how to tune the parameters.

Comment: @Flav maybe there is - the tight little echo I detected may be in fact reverb - I guess a little experimentation is in order!!

Comment: I tried a gated inverted reverb, it kind of does the trick, but I think you are right with the delays.

Comment: Maybe post a section of the song then your hi-hats on some backing Flav?

Answer (score 0):

To me it sounds like they are comb filtered.  But that could be due to tight delay/reverb.

EDIT: try with a short reverb with high send level, and enable the low pass filter on the big mixer channel, set to around 5 kHz.

Comment: Which DAW or VST are you talking about? I am not sure of how to reproduce what you say